# I can't redirect my screen from the login screen to the home page using React Native. TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'props')

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation, react-navigation

I tried a lot of solutions to my problem but none of them worked, got a lot of different errors including navigate wasn't defined, even though it is. I'm new to React native. please Help.
Here is my code for the authentication, I want it to redirect to the Home page using react-navigation.

```
const EmailForm = ({ buttonText, children, onAuthentication, navigation, navigate}) => {
  const [email, onChangeEmail] = useState('')
  const [password, onChangePassword] = useState('')
  const [token, setToken] = useState('');
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');
  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false)
  const [showing, setShowing] = useState(false)
  
  async function submit(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log(email)
    console.log(password)
    axios
      .post('http://Ipv4:5000/api/auth/login', {
        email: email,
        password: password,
      })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data)
        setToken(response.data.token)
        console.log(token)
        setLoggedIn(true)
        setShowing(true)
        
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.response.data)
        setErrorMessage(error.response.data.error)
        setLoggedIn(false)
        setShowing(true)
      })
  }
  return (
    <>
      <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.container}>
        <Image style={styles.image} source={require('./plate.png')} />
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          onChangeText={(text) => onChangeEmail(text)}
          value={email}
          keyboardType="email-address"
          autoCapitalize="none"
        />
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          onChangeText={(text) => onChangePassword(text)}
          value={password}
          secureTextEntry
        />
        <Button title={buttonText} onPress={submit}/>

       
      </ScrollView>
      
      {showing ? <Text>{loggedIn ?   <Text style = {styles.loginmsg}>Success!!</Text> : <Text style={styles.errormsg}> Error! {errorMessage} </Text> } </Text> : null}
      </>
  )
  
}
```

and here is my App.js which has all the screens.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import LoginScreen from './src/screens/LoginScreen';
import HomeScreen from './src/screens/HomeScreen';
import CreateAccountScreen from './src/screens/CreateAccountScreen';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator, navigate} from 'react-navigation-stack';
import _login from './src/screens/_login';
import AdminHome from './src/screens/AdminHome';
import RandomMeals from './src/screens/RandomMeals';
import RandomRestaurants from './src/screens/RandomRestaurants';
import mainScreen from './src/screens/mainScreen';

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(
    {
      mainPg: {
        screen: mainScreen,
      },
      Login: {
        screen: LoginScreen,
      },
      Home: {
        screen: HomeScreen,
      },
      CreateAccount: {
        screen: CreateAccountScreen,
      },
      _login: {
        screen: _login,
      },
      Adhome: {
        screen: AdminHome,
      },
      Meals: {
        screen: RandomMeals,
      },
      Restaurants: {
        screen: RandomRestaurants,
      },  
    },
  );
  // <Router>
  //       <Route exact path="./HomeScreen" component={Home}></Route>
  //       <Route exact path="/login" component={Login}></Route>
  //       <Route exact path="/meals" component={AllMeals}></Route>
  // </Router>

  export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

Comment: Well, `loginn` sort of looks like a React function component, where there is no defined `this` to have any `props` of. Before I vote to close as caused by typo can you double check your code? Is that the "props" that is undefined? Have you included all the relevant code?

Comment: Oh true forgot to take this out, was trying something and it didn't work, please ignore const loginn

Comment: So what `props` is attempting to be read? I don't see it used in the provided code snippet.

Comment: @DrewReese I'm not using props anymore, I'm simply trying to redirect to the home page, see the last line where logged-in is true it returns a Success message, instead I want it to redirect to Home. When I used props, I found the solution online and it didn't work so I took it out, look at the code again if you have time :)

Comment: I see, and can you confirm what routing/navigation library is being used. It looks like react-navigation. Can you show how your routing is organized and how nay "navigate" prop is passed, or should be?

Comment: @DrewReese Yes, I'm using react-navigation stack. I'll post my components above :)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using function component then there is no need to use `this.props.navigation.navigate("Home");` try using `props.navigation.navigate("Home");`

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work. I'm not using props anymore could you please look at the code again? thanks :)

Comment: `history.push({ pathname: "/yourpath", state: { obj: result.data } });` try this , I used it a while ago and it worked for me  here is the link to its doc `https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/history`

Comment: OP is using `react-navigation`, not `react-router-dom`.... completely different library, mate.